# Running CentOS7 on Hyper-V issue with integration service driver

Tags: centos, hyper-v

I installed CentOS 7 on Hyper-V 2012 R2. It seems to be running OK, but I have issue with drivers. And not sure how do I go about updating:

> A storage device have a different version from server.Server version
>   6.0. Client version 5.1. The device will work but this is unsupported configuration....

How do I install proper version? Where do I get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old question but this can be safely ignored according to MS.

> Users are hereby advised to ignore all messages and warnings that seem
>   to indicate that no technical support will be provided because
>   integration services for a non-Windows guest virtual machine are
>   degraded. Microsoft will provide technical support even if when such
>   messages are visible while running supported non-Windows guests on
>   Hyper-V

KB article here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2956569